# image captioning with deep learning

Tags: python, model, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

can anyone help me ..where is the error here?? can anyone help me please. i am trying to train a model for image captioning in persian language.i try to build my model .. below is the code and the model summary.....................

```
`embeddings_dim = 256
input_image_dim = X_train_image.shape[1]

keras.backend.clear_session()

# image model
input_image = keras.layers.Input(shape=(input_image_dim,), name='input_image')
#input_image_dropout = keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(input_image)
image_embeddings = keras.layers.Dense(embeddings_dim, activation='tanh', name='image_embeddings') (input_image)

# text model
# Set up the decoder, using `image_embeddings` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_len,))
embeddings = keras.layers.Embedding(len(word2index), embeddings_dim, mask_zero=True)(decoder_inputs)
#embeddings_dropout = keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(embeddings)
gru = keras.layers.GRU(embeddings_dim)(embeddings, initial_state=image_embeddings) # , return_sequences=True
#flat = keras.layers.Flatten()(gru)
dense = keras.layers.Dense(embeddings_dim, activation='relu')(gru)
#dense_dropout = keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(dense)
decoder_outputs = keras.layers.Dense(len(word2index), activation='softmax')(dense)

seq2seq = keras.Model([input_image, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
seq2seq.summary()

# prepare callback
#histories = My_Callback()

model_checkpoint_path = 'models/model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.3f}--{b1:.3f}.hdf5'
checkpoint_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_checkpoint_path, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
callbacks = [TQDMNotebookCallback(), Bleu_Callback(), checkpoint_callback] #[checkpoint_callback, TQDMNotebookCallback(), My_Callback()]

seq2seq.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy')

seq2seq.fit([X_train_image, X_train_text], y_train_text,
            validation_data=([X_test_image, X_test_text], y_test_text),
            batch_size=1024,
            epochs=10,
            verbose=2,
            callbacks=callbacks) # add My_Callback() to callbacks to calculate & display BLEU score after each epoch`
```

this is the error after running my code .. gives me KeyError: 'metrics'... thanks

```
` Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 20)]         0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_image (InputLayer)       [(None, 1000)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 embedding (Embedding)          (None, 20, 256)      730112      ['input_1[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 image_embeddings (Dense)       (None, 256)          256256      ['input_image[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 gru (GRU)                      (None, 256)          394752      ['embedding[0][0]',              
                                                                  'image_embeddings[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)                  (None, 256)          65792       ['gru[0][0]']                    
                                                                                                  
 dense_1 (Dense)                (None, 2852)         732964      ['dense[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 2,179,876
Trainable params: 2,179,876
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
WARNING:tensorflow:`period` argument is deprecated. Please use `save_freq` to specify the frequency in number of batches seen.
Training: 0%
0/20 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Epoch 0: 0%
0/237 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Epoch 1/20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-0fc16141d8f6> in <module>
     32 seq2seq.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy')
     33 
---> 34 seq2seq.fit([X_train_image, X_train_text], y_train_text,
     35             validation_data=([X_test_image, X_test_text], y_test_text),
     36             batch_size=1024,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_tqdm\tqdm_callback.py in append_logs(self, logs)
    134 
    135     def append_logs(self, logs):
--> 136         metrics = self.params['metrics']
    137         for metric, value in six.iteritems(logs):
    138             if metric in metrics:

KeyError: 'metrics'
```

`

Comment: It looks like a dependency version issue between keras and keras_tqdm, could you add the versions of your packagesas well as the python version ?

Comment: keras 2.9.0 ,  tensorflow 2.8.0, and python 3.9.7,, keras-tqdm

Comment: you did not provide the version of keras_tqdm, you can use import keras_tqdm; keras_tqdm.__version__ to print it. You should edit your questions to add all version numbers.

Comment: keras_tqdm 2.0.1

Comment: so what is the answer?  
Benjamin Breton

Comment: Any help please?? https://stackoverflow.com/users/6651736/benjamin-breton